# Ghostscript ps2pdf not Working Correctly from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, latex, ghostscript

I have a .tex file I am attempting to write from a MATLAB environment (2017b) using first latex, then dvips, and finally ps2pdf to create the PDF file. The PDF file is properly created when I run it through TeXWorks, but sends an error from ps2pdf when I try to run it through. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong with the way I send it to the command line. Here is the script I am attempting to run.

```
    set(groot, 'defaultAxesTickLabelInterpreter','latex'); 
set(groot, 'defaultLegendInterpreter','latex');
set(0,'defaultTextInterpreter','latex');

addpath('C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64')
exampledir='\\our\server\';
examplefilename='test';

texdoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.tex'));
auxdoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.aux'));
logdoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.log'));
dvidoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.dvi'));
psdoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.ps'));
pdfdoc=fullfile(exampledir,strcat(examplefilename,'.pdf'));


fileID = fopen(texdoc,'w');

textext=['\documentclass[twoside]{article} %Two-sided document. Required for fancyhf left and right page numbering scheme current.' newline ...
    '\usepackage{graphicx}' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Use the package fancy header/footer' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.5in,bottom=0.75in,top=0.7in]{geometry} %Ensure the paper is letterpaper.' newline ...
    '\usepackage{grffile}' newline ...
    '\usepackage{caption}' newline ...
    '\usepackage{float} %Float used to position graphics.' newline ...
    '\usepackage{lastpage209} %For last page' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.PDF,.jpg} %Notify LaTeX what type of graphics extensions to expect.' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the header rule' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\pagestyle{fancy} %Use the fancy pagestyle, which will include the fancy header and footer options we defined above.' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\setlength\headheight{38pt} ' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\fancyhead[L]{{Page \thepage}  of \pageref{LastPage}} %Left side on even pages; right side on odd pages.' newline ...
    '\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[trim={0.3in 0.26in 0.05in 0.26in},clip,width=0.4in]{{\\our\server\mypicture}}}' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\begin{document} %This will be the actual document and what goes into it.' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\begin{figure}[h] %Make a figure...' newline ...
          newline ...
    '       \includegraphics[trim={0.25in 0 0 0},clip,width=7.5in]{{\\our\server\mypicture}}' newline ...
    newline ...
    '   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}' newline ...
    newline ...
    '\end{figure}' newline ...
     newline ...
    '\end{document}'];

fprintf(fileID,'%s',textext);

fclose(fileID);

%           latex               dvips            ps2pdf
%   text.tex -------> text.dvi -------> text.ps --------> text.pdf

[~,cmdoutlatex] = system(['latex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory ' exampledir '\ ' texdoc]);

if contains(cmdoutlatex,'Sorry, but latex.exe did not succeed.')

    %Do some kind of check and fix things.
end

[~,cmdoutdvips] = system(['dvips.exe -q* -o ' psdoc ' ' dvidoc]);

if contains(cmdoutdvips,'!')

    %Do some kind of check and fix things.
    error(['Error: ' cmdoutdvips])
end

[~,cmdoutps2pdf] = system(['ps2pdf ' psdoc ' ' pdfdoc ' -sDEVICE=pdfwrite']);

if contains(cmdoutps2pdf,'Error','IgnoreCase',true)

    %Do some kind of check and fix things.
    error(cmdoutps2pdf)
end
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pdflatex`? The output is way better than with `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf`, and the workflow is so much simpler!

Comment: You haven't supplied an example PostScript file to reproduce the problem, you haven't given the back channel output from Ghostscript, and you haven't stated the nature of the error. Without that its impossible to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Switching from the manual `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf` methods to `pdflatex` worked well. For some reason I had originally switched from `pdflatex` as it was not working in MATLAB 2017b's environment, but now it seems to be working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Cris Luengo's suggestion of moving to `pdflatex` rather than using `latex`/`dvips`/`ps2pdf` commands, this worked. Here is the sample code of what worked for a system command.

```
[~,pdflatexout] = system(['pdflatex.exe -output-directory ' strrep(exampledir,'\','/') ' ' texdoc]);

%Check for errors.
if contains(pdflatexout,'Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.') || ...
        contains(pdflatexout,'error','IgnoreCase',true)

    %Deliver the error code.
    error(pdflatexout)
end
```

I placed this after `fclose(fileID)` in the original code and deleted all that had originally come after that line.